# What kind/type of connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector, automotive

What is the name/type of this window switch connector?

It is from a 2012 Tesla Model S but I believe it is made by Mercedes Benz. I have looked all over the internet and can not find a connector that matches.

I don't have an unbroken one to photograph with a ruler as mine is broken, but it is about 5/8 to 1/2 inch wide.

[image: Window switch 2012 Tesla model s]

Comment: please add a scale (ruler) to the image so we can see how big it is.

Comment: What makes you think it's a Molex connector, rather than TE or maybe JST?

Comment: I don't have an unbroken one to measure. This is from a used wire harness but it is about 1/2" to 5/8" wide. I also. do not know if it is Molex, that is the only connector name I know, I will look up TE or maybe JST, thanks

Comment: "about " is not good enough. Please measure precisely, in mm. See: https://forum.digikey.com/t/pitch-of-a-connector/172

Comment: "Mercedes Benz": automotive connectors are rarely identifiable. Ask the Mercedes Benz dealer's parts department.

Comment: @mj662 Molex is not the name of a type of connector, it's the name of a company that makes connectors.

Comment: Step 1 is to measure the distance between the two outermost pins, then divide by the number of pins to get the pitch. 2mm is common but there's no telling from a picture.